# Velocity array to javascript array

Tags: javascript, velocity

I need to pass a velocity string array to JavaScript function. So, for that, I want to convert the velocity array into JavaScript array.

The source code looks like this :

```
String[] arrStr[] = new String[3];
arrStr[0] = "String 1";
arrStr[1] = "String 2";
arrStr[2] = "String 3";
request.setAttribute("a", arrStr);
```

In my HTML template,

```
#set ( #arr = $request.getAttribute("a"))

<script language="javascript">

var newArr = "${arr}";

</script>
```

But the string arrays are not copied to newArr. Can anyone help me out on this ?

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
var newArr = [ 
#foreach( $var in $arr )#if($foreach.index>  0),#end "$var" #end 
];
```

Comment: What if `$var`'s value contains `"`? Or line breaks? Or backslashes?

Answer (score 1):

This is a really good question, I tried countless solutions and nothing that seemed reasonable couldn't make an array of strings, everything resulted in [param1, param2] instead of ["param1", "param2"] and to an error "param1 is not defined".

However I was able to resolve it by using #foreach as a parameter and rest parameter.

In HTML:

```
functionName(
  #foreach($obj in $array)
      #if ($velocityCount != $array.size())'$obj',
      #else'$obj'
      #end
  #end
)
```

In Javascript:

```
functionName(...args)
```

...args is a [rest parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters), which "represents an indefinite number of arguments as an array". So if you need other parameters besides the array, remember to put them before the array:

```
functionName(param1, param2, ...args)
```

Comment: What if `$obj`'s value contains `'`? Or line breaks? Or backslashes?